# How to locate a house on the 3D Map correctly?

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-system, mathematics, 3d-map, position

I've done my 3D map generation in WebGL/THREE.JS project and have an issue with the building locations.

I have the data about building position ( its polygon ) from DB server, but first of all I want just to locate not the polygon data, but a simple cube. The aim is clear is as a crystal: `to set a building to the correct position by putting a cube on the 3D map.`

Now it does look like:

[image]

I have demonstrated it, because I want to admit, that to create a building and place it on the map - isn't a problem. The problem is to set building into the correct position/location on the map.

What I have done before?

Because the building record has two fields in DB:

```
position on map ( lat | long ) | polygon data of building ( points collection )
```

I thought that I must convert the geospatial coordinates of each building: latitude, longitude to its cartesian values, because WebGL/THREE.JS don't work with the shperical/geographic coordinates system.

So I have built also a JSON web-service which helps in data transformations and similar aims.

For e.g. the conversion of the point { 38.23, 55.89 } to its cartesian representation:

[image]

Now... I'm really confused how to use it for locating the building correctly on the map. 
If you would like see, I'm prinring the position of each building in console:

[image]

Spherical coordinates and converting at web-service side by such formula in my C# code:

```
internal Models.PointCartesian ConvertFromSphericalToCartesian(double angleTheta, double anglePhi)
{
    var radTheta = ConvertDegreesToRadians(angleTheta);
    var radPhi = ConvertDegreesToRadians(anglePhi);

    var model = new Models.PointCartesian()
    {
        X = earthRadius * Math.Cos(radTheta) * Math.Cos(radPhi),
        Y = earthRadius * Math.Cos(radTheta) * Math.Sin(radPhi),
        Z = earthRadius * Math.Sin(radTheta)
    };

    return model;
}
```

So... Right now I'm thinking about some proportions to use... But this way can be incorrect... So what's your suggestion how to set a cube into the correct position on the 3D map just for showing the real position of some buildings.

PS:
The records lat | long of each building in DB is 100% correct.
Thanks!

Comment: any solution for this problem using osm tiles,gltf model and  threejs/javascript?